# Use Include and Where in Find Method in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this code in my controllers:

```
var project = await _context.Projects
            .Include(p => p.Customer)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Project_Id == id);
```

But I want to use in generic repository that I write this method

Generic Repository:

```
public async Task<T> GetByIdIncludes(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string includes = "")
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate).Include(includes).FirstOrDefaultAsync();  
}
```

and in my controller replace with this code

My Controller:

```
var project = await _genericRepository.GetByIdIncludes(F => F.Customer_Id == id, "Customer");
```

but the `FindByIdInclude` method in the generic repository was returned `null` to the controller, why?

Comment: Not sure, but what would happen if you put include before where in your sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put include before where in your sample

```
public async Task<T> GetByIdIncludes(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string includes = "")
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<T>().Include(includes).Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();  
        }
```